# Ninject thread blocking issue on high traffic site

Tags: .net, performance, iis, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

We just started our peak season and our traffic is causing some performance issues. We used LeanSentry to try to diagnose the issue, and the techs over there said that something in Ninject is blocking threads.

Below you will find the screenshots they sent and they also said quote "We've seen a number of issues with Ninject and circular dependencies/deadlocks, you may get some info by poking around online.".

We are currently using 3.2.2.0 version.  Is this a common thing with Ninject.  Should I look into a faster IOC?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a fact that Ninject is rather slow. There's plenty of benchmarks out there. So yes, if profiling shows Ninject is taking significant time it can make sense to look into other DI containers.

Comment: You definitely should switch to a faster IoC if possible. In the meantime, the scan does indicate issues of KB821268, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/821268/contention-poor-performance-and-deadlocks-when-you-make-calls-to-web-s which you might also tune ASP.NET thread pool if you want.

Comment: I am looking into SimpleInjector, but on a time crunch here so that wont be done until next week most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched out `Ninject` with `SimpleInjector` and my CPU now is normally under 5% for the site, even during peek hours.